# How to give hover effect for the star code when selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement the star-rating, and i am using the bootstrap icons features and I am using the star icons for this from bootstrap. I am able to get all the features of a star rating but i am not getting the hover effect for the previous siblings.

For example: if i hover to star4 then it should make the color of star1,2,3 to some color. but i am unable to get that feature.

My code is :

```
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star1" id="q6-1" value="1"></span>
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star1" id="q6-2" value="2"></span>
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star1" id="q6-3" value="3"></span>
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star1" id="q6-4" value="4"></span>
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star1" id="q6-5" value="5"></span>
```

Jquery Is:

```
 $('.star1').click(function(){
 var rating = $(this).attr('id');
 var res = rating.split("-");
 rating = res[1]; 

 for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
   if(i<=rating){
        $('#q6-'+i).addClass("color-star"); 
   }       
 }
 alert(rating);
 });

$('.star1').hover(function(){
 $(this).addClass("color-star");
 }, function() {
 $(this).removeClass("color-star");

});
```

Comment: What happened to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404904/how-to-use-bootstrap-icons-like-star-to-give-the-star-rating/23404979#23404979

Comment: actually i am not that gud at CSS. So i am trying to implement with Jquery.

Comment: If you don't want answers using CSS then, why you have tagged your question with CSS? __Use tag wisely__

Comment: @anand - you are better using CSS where possible, as that is its purpose- I've posted a fairly simple implementation below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [CSS Implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/52VtD/5091/)

HTML

```
<div class='rating'> 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star1" id="q6-1" value="1"></span>
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star1" id="q6-2" value="2"></span>
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star1" id="q6-3" value="3"></span>
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star1" id="q6-4" value="4"></span>
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star1" id="q6-5" value="5"></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.rating{
    float:left;
}
.star1{
    float:right;
}
.star1:hover, .star1:hover ~ .star1{
    color:gold;    
}
```

---

### [jQuery Implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/52VtD/5093/)

```
$('.star1').hover(function(){
   $(this).css('color', 'gold').prevAll('.star1').css('color', 'gold');
 }, function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'black').prevAll('.star1').css('color', 'black');
});
```

Or, using your code:

```
$('.star1').hover(function(){
   $(this).addClass("color-star").prevAll('.star1').addClass("color-star");
 }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("color-star").prevAll('.star1').removeClass("color-star");
});
```

Comment: what does last css means.. Is there any tutorial or link where i can learn these things .. such as the last tricky CSS